# Saving Contacts after accessing to sharedprefs

Tags: android

I have accessed the contacts from my app but i would know how to save the two textview to shared prefs. Code is running fine except that im unable to store it to shared prefs.

```
contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            pickContact(null);
            String a = tvCname.getText().toString();
            String b = tvCnum.getText().toString();
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("Name",a);
            editor.putString("Phone Number",b);
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

this is the code for accessing contacts in phone.

```
 public void pickContact(View v)
{
    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, RESULT_PICK_CONTACT);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // check whether the result is ok
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Check for the request code, we might be usign multiple startActivityForResult
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RESULT_PICK_CONTACT:
                contactPicked(data);
                //test

                break;
            case 99:
                Intent intentReceived = data;
                String strName = intentReceived.getStringExtra("name");
                String strBT = intentReceived.getStringExtra("bloodType");
                String strNum =  intentReceived.getStringExtra("number");
                String strAddress = intentReceived.getStringExtra("address");
                String strOther = intentReceived.getStringExtra("other");

                tvName.setText(strName);
                tvBg.setText(strBT);
                tvNum.setText(strNum);
                tvAddress.setText(strAddress);
                tvOther.setText(strOther);
                Toast.makeText(this,"Profile added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
    } else {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Failed to pick contact");
    }
}
/**
 * Query the Uri and read contact details. Handle the picked contact data.
 * @param data
 */
private void contactPicked(Intent data) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String phoneNo = null ;
        String cName = null;
        // getData() method will have the Content Uri of the selected contact
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        //Query the content uri
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        // column index of the phone number
        int  phoneIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
        // column index of the contact name
        int  nameIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
        phoneNo = cursor.getString(phoneIndex);
        cName = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
        // Set the value to the textviews

        tvCname.setText(phoneNo);
        tvCnum.setText(cName);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To save values to SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);    //MyPREFERENCES is a string for find your SharedPreferences
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("key1", "value1");
editor.putString("key1", "value1");
editor.commit();
```

To get this values back

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);    
String value1=sharedpreferences.getString("key1", null);
String value2=sharedpreferences.getString("key2", null);
```

Comment: Which part of the code do i need to put in sharepref to save the contact number and name ?

Comment: SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefidentifier", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString("Name",a);
            editor.putString("Phone Number",b);
            editor.commit();
This code use for save the values;
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefidentifier", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String name=sharedpreferences.getString("Name", null);
String phone=sharedpreferences.getString("Phone Number", null);
This code use for return the value.